# Jungledisk: cause directory/files to be cached

Tags: macos, jungledisk

I'm trying to cause a directory structure stored in JungleDisk (running OSX) to be pulled into the local cached. When I try to use the command line, the directories that are not already in the cache report as "No such file or directory" so it doesn't seem like I can use a "find" script from the command line to cause JungleDisk to pull down the file into the cache.

The finder seems to pull files down to try to render a preview, but it seems to only do that for the files that are visible in the current finder window. It would be a pain to have to babysit every directory via the finder to get files into the cache.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this seems osx dependent, so I don't know how well it will work on other systems.

In the finder, right click on the root of the directory structure you want to cache and select "Get Info".  This will cause all the "meta data" information on each file and directory to be pulled down into the cache so the command line will work (ls, find, etc).

From there you can run:

```
for i in `find .`; do md5 "$i"; done
```

Which should cause every file to be pulled down into the cache.  I'm still not sure how to initiate this process without the aid of the finder, so the answer is still incomplete.